# Lan-based authentication of applications and secure channel

Tags: c++, authentication, ssl, ssh, application-security

I've a server which authenticates clients applications and allows them to execute or not. I want to have a secure channel between server and clients. I've written my server with both [ssl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) and [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) protocols but I don't know which one must be used in these scenario and which one is more logical.

both client and server has been written in Qt,c++.

ssl is mostly used in https and web based application and ssh is used for remote administration, so I think that ssh is more appropriate for my server. also I think it's not a good design if I release my application with certificates(exe file along with a certificate.)

Answer (score 0):

Both `ssl` and `ssh` use the same, fundamental, cryptographic technologies. Looks like you understand the practical differences between the two, so use whichever one is convenient for your application. As long as you follow proper security practices (keeping your certificates and/or private keys under a watchful eye, etc etc etc), either one will give you the same, basic, level of security.